# SQL bulk log exception row

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I've searched for it and couldn't find anything helpful. I am reading files from FTP and processing them for information. I need to ask that is there anyway to find the specific row at which the exception has occurred in SQL BULK LOG.

Exception in my program is as follows.

> "The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetime of the specified target column."

I want to know the row at which the exception is occurring and want to log it to the database.

Please don't do negative votes if question is not clear then I can clarify further.

Comment: Show some values which are being converted  to date.

Comment: @Utsav... Actually that datetime cell is empty that's why this error is happening. My problem is that i want to retrieve the row at which the exception has occurred.

Comment: I understand that, but for input data, which is the column you are using to convert it to datetime. Can you give some example of that column and also how are you processing it to convert to datetime.

Comment: 12/24/2016  8:30:00 PM

This is an example which is working absolutely fine. The problem occurs when empty cell is executed for datetme conversion.

Comment: So for the columns, use `nvl` function. Something like `nvl(column_name,to_date('01/01/1901','DD/MM/YYYY'))`. So for `null` you will read the date at `01/01/1901`. And in your code, you can handle it

Comment: SQL BULK LOG processes the whole file at once. This is not my problem's solution what you just told me. I want to know that **"is there any way to know that specific row at which error/exception has occurred regardless of the its column type".**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137044/discussion-between-muhammad-omer-and-utsav).

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do what you are asking. I was suggesting how to handle it. Lets hope someone else can help you on that. Cheers!